# Facebook: OAuthException: (#200) Must have a valid access_token to access this endpoint

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

i am trying to fetch all the public events from facebook,

when i try to execute my php code from my server i get the error: **Uncaught OAuthException: (#200) Must have a valid access_token to access this endpoint thrown in /....../sdk/src/base_facebook.php on line 1254**

while if i execute the same code on heroku... it works.... i want to execute the code on my server.... plz help.... my code is.. :

```
    <?php

require_once('utils.php');

require_once('sdk/src/facebook.php');

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '.........',
  'secret' => '..............',
  'sharedSession' => true,
  'trustForwarded' => true,
));

$events =idx($facebook->api('/search?q=trade&type=event&limit=5000&access_token=ksdkslhosihgksjdhlshfshdfgskdjhsklfhsklfhskfjhsdlkhslhslh'), 'data', array());

$var=1;

foreach($events as $event)
{

    $id = idx($event, 'id');
    $name = idx($event, 'name');
    $owner = idx($event, 'owner');
    $start_time = idx($event, 'start_time');
    $end_time = idx($event, 'end_time');
    $location = idx($event, 'location');
    $description = idx($event, 'description');
     echo "S.No:".$var."<br>";
     echo "ID:".he($id)."<br>";
     echo "Name:".he($name)."<br>";
     echo "Owner:".he($owner)."<br>";
     echo "start_time:".he($start_time)."<br>";
     echo "end_time:".he($end_time)."<br>";
     echo "location:".he($location)."<br>";
     echo "description:".he($description)."<br>";
     $var=$var+1;
}   

?>
```

the util.php file used is same as in heroku.....

util.php

```
    <?php

/**
 * @return the value at $index in $array or $default if $index is not set.
 */
function idx(array $array, $key, $default = null) {
  return array_key_exists($key, $array) ? $array[$key] : $default;
}

function he($str) {
  return htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
}
```

Comment: You might want to double-check that Facebook provided you with a valid OAuth token and that your FB app allows you to go through the domain you are trying to go through.

Answer (score -1):

It might be related to this

[Facebook bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/453298034751100?browse=search_516534c213df06064266897)

Comment: That bug refers to email address searches across the Graph, not searches for public posts.